# Set different style for child of class in css

Tags: html, css, font-size

Except to see two different font-size, but both have same font-size

```
<div class="entry">
<h3>Headquarter 1</h3>
</div>

<div class="h3-block">
<h3>Headquarter 2</h3>
</div>

.h3-block > .h3, h3 {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.entry > .h3, h3 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put `,h3` you apply all h3 tags as `font-size: 1.75rem;` remove it.

Another missing is that `.h3` means that you have element whose class is `h3` but you dont have like that class you need to write `h3`

```
.h3-block > h3{
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.entry > h3 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
}
```

if u have default font size for h3 also put top of others

```
h3{
   font-size: 1.125rem;// here your default value
}
.h3-block > h3{
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}
.entry > h3 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.h3-block > h3 {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.entry > h3 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
<h3>Headquarter 1</h3>
</div>

<div class="h3-block">
<h3>Headquarter 2</h3>
</div>
```